# Get string value of class propery names in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have the following class definition.

Contact.h

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Contact :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * City;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * LastUpdated;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Country;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * Id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * ContactNotes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * State;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * StreetAddress2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * DateCreated;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * FirstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Phone1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * PostalCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Website;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * StreetAddress1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * LastName;

@end
```

Is it possible to obtain an array of NSString objects with all of the properties by name?

Array would look like this...

```
[@"City", @"LastUpdated", @"Country", .... ]
```

**Solution (updated based on comment)**

Thanks to Dave's answer I was able to write the following method to be used

```
- (NSMutableArray *) propertyNames: (Class) class { 
    NSMutableArray *propertyNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    unsigned int propertyCount = 0;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(class, &propertyCount);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < propertyCount; ++i) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        const char * name = property_getName(property);
        [propertyNames addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:name]];
    }
    free(properties);
    return [propertyNames autorelease];
}
```

Comment: You should `return [propertyNames autorelease];` to follow memory management guidelines.  Also, why not just pass in a `Class` object instead of a string to convert to a `Class` object?

Comment: This should also be a free function or a class method, rather than an instance method.

Comment: @dreamlax does having it as a class method make much of a difference if I am using it privately within a singleton? (still new in objc)

Comment: It is more logical for it to be a class method because it doesn't depend on the state of an instance (it doesn't reference any instance variables). If a method doesn't depend on the state of an instance, it should be a class method. The output is entirely dependent only on the `class` parameter, so it should be a class method or free function. Alternatively you could make it a class category method that operates on the current class.

Comment: Well, actually that's not entirely true, but generally speaking it is the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep!  Here you go:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

//somewhere:
unsigned int propertyCount = 0;
objc_property_t * properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &propertyCount);

NSMutableArray * propertyNames = [NSMutableArray array];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < propertyCount; ++i) {
  objc_property_t property = properties[i];
  const char * name = property_getName(property);
  [propertyNames addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:name]];
}
free(properties);
NSLog(@"Names: %@", propertyNames);
```

Warning: code typed in browser.

Answer (score 2):

You could call [`dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000471-BABIAGCF) and then call the `allValues` method on that dictionary to get an array of values. Note that you'll need to convert the non-`NSString` properties to strings yourself.

Comment: That gives you the values of the specified keys.  It seems like @Flash84x wants a list of keys.

Comment: What would I pass to `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:`?